# If else if statement doesnt work with get

Tags: php, if-statement

Hey guys Im having problem with if else if with $_GET. Im trying to include page based on GET on page.
Navigation code

```
<a href="index.php?page=setting">Setting</a>
<a href="index.php?page=post">Post Article</a>
```

Php Code

```
<? 
if($_GET['page']=='post' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0 || $_GET['page']=='setting' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0)
{
include "page/post.php";

}else if{

include "page/setting.php";

}else{
include "page/home.php";
?>
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `}else if(SOME COMDITION){` write some condition here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a condition for the else if:

```
<? 
if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='post' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0){
    include "page/post.php";
}else if(isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page']=='setting' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0){
    include "page/setting.php";
}else{
    include "page/home.php";
}
?>
```

I have added as well a security check, just to be sure that the $_GET['page'] variable exists (isset returns true if the variable is set).

If you don't have this variable in your url, you could have problems without this check.

UPDATE:
If you have more pages, I would suggest using a router ;-) (Laravel framework has one).

But to keep it simple, this is like this:

```
<? 

$pageArray = [
    'post' => 'page/post.php',
    'home' => 'page/home.php',
    'test' => 'page/test.php'
];

if(isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $page = null;
}
if($page && isset($pageArray[$page]) && $_SESSION['status'] > 0){
    include $pageArray[$page];
}else{
    include "page/home.php";
}
?>
```

Always make sure that you NEVER do `include $_GET['page'];`, or someone could just do something like http://youwebsite.com?page=http://hackerwebsite.com
and you would include his page in your server, potentially causing damages.

So always check that you know the requested page (that's what I check with `isset($pageArray[$page])`)

Comment: if I have 2 more page how do I do it?

Comment: @aviva, please refer to my answer. I have added a facility to add more pages. Look into the optimised code section.

Comment: Or use `in_array($page, $pageArray)` to check if route is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

Correct the syntax of else if

`else if` need brackets around it.

e.g `else if ($test == TRUE)`

**Corrected Code:**

```
if($_GET['page']=='post' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0) {
    include "page/post.php";
}
else if ($_GET['page']=='setting' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0) {
    include "page/setting.php";
}
else {
    include "page/home.php";
}
?>
```

**More optimised code:**

```
if ($_SESSION['status'] > 0) {
    $pages = array();
    $pages['post'] = 'post';
    $pages['setting'] = 'setting';
    // You can add more pages, by adding entries in this array. 
    //e.g. $pages['about'] = 'about';
    if (isset($_GET['page']) && isset($pages[$_GET['page']])) {
        $page = $pages[$_GET['page']];
        include "page/" . $page . ".php";
    }
}
else {
    include "page/home.php";
}
```

Comment: Well done! Little hint: If `key` is always equal `value`, then you can only use the `values` in your `$pages` array, c.f. [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31693462/1828051).

Comment: @GottliebNotschnabel, I have checked your answer, quite decent. You are correct. This is for future purpose, say, if OP has a page where key and values may be different.

Comment: Yes you're right. In that case OP should use a `key => value` array.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly improved version of [Pupil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31692706/1828051):

```
if ($_SESSION['status'] > 0) {
    $pages = array(
        'post',
        'setting',
        'whatever' // add pages
    );

    if (isset($_GET['page']) && in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)) {
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        include "page/" . $page . ".php";
    }
}
else {
    include "page/home.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And be sure that the session status isset and > 0.

```
if($_GET['page']=='post' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0)
{
    include "page/post.php";
} else if($_GET['page']=='setting' && $_SESSION['status'] > 0) {
    include "page/setting.php";
} else {
    include "page/home.php";
}
```